# CakePHP nesting select query

Tags: sql, cakephp, select, nested

I have 3 db tables: books(id, title, author,...) and orders(id, book_id, user_id,...) and users(id, name, username,...) and I would like to get the titles of the books ordered by given user.

I prepared query using query() method:

```
$this->set('user_orders', $this->Order->query("SELECT orders.id, orders.status, 
(SELECT books.title FROM books WHERE books.id = orders.book_id) as `titles`
FROM orders WHERE orders.user_id = ".$this->Auth->user('id').""));
```

Now, I would like to obtain the same result but using find() method:

```
$this->set('user_orders', $this->Order->find('all', array(
                                        'fields' => array(
                                            'Order.id', 
                                            'status',   
                                            'Order.book_id',                                        
                                            'Book.title' => $this->Book->find('first',array(
                                                'fields' => 'Book.title',
                                                'conditions'=> array('Book.id = Order.id')
                                                )),
                                            ),
                                        'conditions' => array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')))));
```

However, it does not work. How it should be corrected to obtain the same effect like in code above?

Greetings

Comment: Please specify the associations you have between your models

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work" - be more specific.  Also, you're not specifying an `ORDER`.  Lastly - I would guess your condition should be `Book.id = Order.book_id`, not `Order.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read up on the ContainableBehavior for this: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1323/Containable.

And, as Kaklon suggested: please be more specific about what is/isn't working...